# Material design lite FAB soft keyboard popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I am working on a UI/UX project for interface redesign. I am using bootstrap, Google Material design lite mostly. I am trying to use any plugin to help me popup soft android keyboard when clicked on the FAB button. However I am unable to do so. Someone please help me out with this. I have shared the code file below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap fonts and icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">

    <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>



 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jkeyboard.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jkeyboard.css">

    <title>Swipes Redesign</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
 <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">NOW</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <button id="demo-menu-top-right"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>
<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    data-mdl-for="demo-menu-top-right">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Multi Select</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Search</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Workspace</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Settings</li>
</ul>
      
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title"></span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Past Tasks</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Completed Tasks</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="cards.html">Folders</a>
    
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!--<main class="mdl-layout__content"> -->
    <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here -->
     <!-- <div class="list-group">
  
  <a href="hmk.html" class="list-group-item">Homework HCI</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Prototype Design</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Buy Eggs, Milk and bread</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Purchase  car tool set from amazon</a>
</div> -->

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
 <!-- </main> -->











  <!-- Colored FAB button with ripple -->
  <!-- want to trigger soft keyboard when clicked on this button-->
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
  <i class="material-icons">+</i>
   
</button>

</div>

</div>







    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function() { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>
  </body>
</html>
```